# How can I correct the typescript error? (prop-Types library)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

This is my first time using the prop-types library.

This is my error message.

- Binding element 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type.
- Binding element 'email' implicitly has an 'any' type.
- Binding element 'gender' implicitly has an 'any' type.

This is my code.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function Row({ name, email, gender }) {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{email}</p>
      <p>{gender}</p>
    </>
  );
}

Row.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  email: PropTypes.string,
  gender: PropTypes.string,
};
```

I think there is not wrong part. I need you help how can i fix my error without 'interface' or 'type'.

Comment: If this is typescript then you don't need PropTypes

Comment: Check https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: That's something I was completely mistaken about. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're writing Typescript as opposed to Javascript.

Proptypes is used to achieve the idea of static typing in Javascript, but if you're writing Typescript then you need to define an interface for your props like this.

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  gender: string;
}

export default function Row({ name, email, gender }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{email}</p>
      <p>{gender}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't know properly from the first premise. Thank you!!